После сборки программы .Net 8 в автономный exe файл, программа не видит файл базы данных
Есть файл базы данных, который программа не видит после сборки в автономный файл, он лежит в самой верхней папке проекта\Data\database.sdf.
Но после сборки автономного файла и после запуска
exe происходит исключение, оно обрабатывается, и пишется что нет подключения к базе данных, возможно нарушаются пути, так как этот файл ищется в коде либо по названию (это и есть путь, если он лежит сразу рядом с ехе), либо поднимается на два уровня вверх и заходит в фолдер Data, и там берётся.
В этом и заключается вопрос, файл бд либо не зашивается в exe, либо зашивается, но имеет другой путь, кто знает эту проблему?
